# Two key shortcuts

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyside

I am trying to set up two-key shortcuts without modifiers in Pyside/PyQt4.

I have tried various combinations of QEvents and QKeySequences, but to no avail.

What I would like to do is something like this:

def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    if (event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_O) and (event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_P ):
        print('shortcut op accepted')

or

```
fileMenu.addAction(QtGui.QAction("Open Project", self, shortcut=QtGui.QKeySequence("P" and "O"),triggered=self.openProject))
```

where the users presses, O, then P and then the action occurs.

Does anyone know firstly if this is possible and if so how to do it?

Comment: The `and` operator for strings cannot be the right thing here because `"P" and "O"` is just `"O"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me `"O, P"` as arguments for the `QKeySequence` do the job.

Example:

```
from PySide import QtGui

def beep():
    print('beep')

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

toolbar = QtGui.QToolBar()
toolbar.show()

action = QtGui.QAction("Action", toolbar, shortcut=QtGui.QKeySequence("O, P"), triggered=beep)
toolbar.addAction(action)

app.exec_()
```

Comment: Using "O, P" as arguments for the QKeySequence worked fine and it appears that I can do it all in one line:

fileMenu.addAction(QtGui.QAction("Open Project", self, shortcut=QtGui.QKeySequence("O, P"), triggered=self.openProject))

This also shows the key sequence in the file menu next to the command.

Comment: @user3767797 I would like to draw your attention to the "set the answer as accepted answer" checkmark in case the answer solves the question. Consider checking it if my answer did solve your question to your satisfaction.